# Twitter Boostrap Carousel won't wrap, invents new blank slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have tried quite a few different solutions on here but none of them seem to work. I have Bootstrap in a WordPress install, I'm calling jQuery before bootstrap.js, and the transitions seem to look like they should. The only problem is it does not wrap. It plays through the first 3 slides and then presents a blank slide, which doesn't even exist in the markup.

Then it gets stuck there and the buttons stop working. Is that how you do data-wrap="true"? I think the Bootstrap documentation is rubbish in this area. I'm using BS 3.1.

EDIT: SOLVED.

Turns out I just needed to install a wordpress plugin, Disable WPAutoP. WordPress was inserting an empty tag into the carousel and that's what was causing the weird behaviour.

Comment: If you care to see a demo, have a look at http://avsecurity.focalisewebdesign.com

Comment: Ok after staring at Firebug for a while, I've spotted a mysterious <p> tag that I can't find in my markup anywhere. The "active" class gets passed around the slides as it should until it gets assigned to this mystery <p>, and then it all gets stuck. Is wordpress inserting this <p> do you think? I have examined my markup, but I can't find what is causing that <p> tag. I'm sure someone else has had this exact problem...